# Loading a livewire component inside a modal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

#### Description

I am trying to dynamically load a Livewire component inside a modal, using Livewire. I can successfully load the HTML content in the modal, but any Javascript on the "target" component is not executed.

#### Exact steps to reproduce

```html
<!-- index.blade.php -->
<div>
   <a onclick="showTask(1)">Open task #1</a>
   @includeWhen($openTask, 'partials.tasks._task_modal')
</div>
```

```php
//Index.php 
function showTask(int $taskId){
        $this->managingTask = true;
        $this->openTask = Task::firstWhere('id', $taskId);
}
```

So in the above code, when a user clicks the `a` tag, it will open the modal, placed in:

```html
<!-- _task_modal.blade.php -->
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="managingTask">
    <x-slot name="content">
        @livewire('tasks.show', ['task' => $openTask])
    </x-slot>
</x-jet-dialog-modal>
```

As you can see, the modal component simply refers to another Livewire component called `tasks.show`. Inside this, I have the following in the view file:

```html
<!-- show.blade.php -->
<div>
   <a onclick="test()">Test</a>
</div>
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            alert("It works!")
        }
       document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
          console.log("Livewire Loaded");
      });
  </script>
@endpush
```

This is my layout file:

```html
<!-- app.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
    @livewireStyles
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>


</head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased" >

<div id="root" x-data>
 {{$slot}}
</div>
@stack('modals')
@livewireScripts
@stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when clicking on the `a` link inside the `show.blade.php` Livewire component, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Further, I do not see the "Livewire Loaded" in my console.

**Context**

- Livewire version:  2.3.6
- Laravel version: 8.12
- Browser: Chrome

Comment: Do you stack your scripts in the layout?

Comment: @Qirel Yes, I do that in the layout file. I have updated my question to include the code of my `app.blade.php` file.